How does one perform an $S$ gate on a surface code patch using lattice surgery?
I'm attempting to understand how to perform universal quantum computation via lattice surgery. I'm struggling to find any resources for $S$ gates with lattice surgery. I would greatly appreciate an explanation/links to good resources.

In lattice surgery, you perform $S$ gates by preparing a $Y$ state and then permanently merging the $Y$ state into the target qubit:
 
See "Inplace Access to the Surface Code Y Basis" for how to measure and prepare $Y$ states within a surface code patch:



Also see "Poking holes and cutting corners to achieve Clifford gates with the surface code
", which is where it was originally noticed that $S$ gates are equivalent to braiding surface code twists:




Thank you for your answer. This is super helpful!
